# Why are the tips of my hardneck garlic plants dying?

Tags: leaves, growth, garlic

I've noticed that the tips of my hard neck garlic leaves are dying, and was wondering if this is normal, or not, because the flower stalk hasn't come up yet.

Time:right before summer
Location:full sun flower bed

[image: hardneck garlic dying tips]
What am I doing wrong/right?
What should I do for them?

Comment: When did you plant it? What has the weather been like? First guess is too much or not enough water, though "not enough" can also be achieved with spring-planted garlic and adequate soil moisture (but inadequate root development from having been spring planted)

Comment: Also location could be useful. It is normal, if the plant is old (and garlic is ready to be collected, before it will growth again).

Comment: They  were planted about 2 months ago, and they're in the flower bed.

Comment: Location as in which continent, what season etc.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for inadequate moisture from being spring planted. They look pretty healthy, just young. I would wait them out. They should sprout their hard neck and then flower, all before the adult leaves begin to yellow and dry out. I planted my hardneck in the fall and harvested early August. Yours should be ready late September/early October if you planted in late May.